# Enhanced Drupal User Administration

Tags: drupal

Drupal's user administration page @ admin/user/user allows admins to checkmark users & perform bulk operations on the selected accounts (ie: adding roles to users). Contrib modules can add to the list of available user operations that can be performed. Very handy.

The interface, however, only allows the administrator to deal with a single page of users at a time. For example, if I checkmark 12 users on page 1, when I navigate to page 2 I lose track of who was selected on the first page.

I'd like to know if there is a contrib module that enhances the interface so that an administrator can select records across several pages of users before choosing an Update option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) will get this done. It will require views, but it does facilitate selecting all records in a result to apply the action to, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow, you are so right! I had always incorrectly assumed that VBO was for nodes only.